# Reflect Day light savings in Salesforce

Tags: datetime, timezone

I have a custom objects where there are many datetime fields with respect to  different timezones.

How does the time adjust incase of day light savings? Will salesforce reflects the new time automatically? or what would be the approach if we want to reflect new time in all the existing records?

Comment: All times are stored in GMT format, and only converted into the user's timezone when being displayed on the forms or reports

Answer (score 1):

Date and Date/Time values are stored in GMT. When a record is saved, field values are adjusted from the user’s time zone to GMT, and then adjusted back to the viewer’s time zone when displayed in record detail pages and reports. With Date conversions this doesn't pose a problem, since converting a Date/Time to a Date results in the same Date value.

When working with Date/Time fields and values, however, the conversion is always done in GMT, not the user’s time zone. Subtracting a standard Date/Time field from another isn’t a problem because both fields are in the same time zone. When one of the values in the calculation is a conversion from a Text or Date value to a Date/Time value, however, the results are different.
 Let’s say a San Francisco user enters a value of 12:00 AM on August 2, 2013 in a custom Date/Time field called Date_Time_c. This value is stored as 2013–08–02 07:00:00Z, because the time difference in Pacific Daylight Time is GMT-7. At 12:00 p.m. PDT on August 1st, the user views the record and the following formula : Date_Time_c - NOW()
  calculate, NOW() is 2013–08–01 19:00:00Z, and then subtracted from 2013–08–02 07:00:00Z, to return the expected result of 0.5 (12 hours).
 Suppose that instead of NOW(), the formula converts the string “2013–08–01 12:00:00” to a Date/Time value:  Date_Time_c - DATETIMEVALUE( "2013-08-01 12:00:00" ) 
 In this case, DATETIMEVALUE( “2013–08–01 12:00:00” ) is 2013–08–01 12:00:00Z, and returns a result of 0.79167, or 19 hours. 
There’s no way to determine a user’s time zone in a formula. If all of your users are in the same time zone, you can adjust the time zone difference by adding or subtracting the time difference between the users’ time zone and GMT to your converted values. However, since time zones can be affected by Daylight Saving Time, and the start and end dates for DST are different each year, this is difficult to manage in a formula. We recommend using Apex for transactions that require converting between Date/Time values and Text or Date values.